# Flutter - Google Maps doesn´t wait to Location

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I´m trying to show a map with current location. For do this i used [**Location**](https://pub.dev/packages/location#-readme-tab-) and [**Google Map**](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) plugins (last version).

I have a code similar to:

```
var lng, lat;

          @override
          initState() {
            super.initState();
            loading = true;
            getLocation();
          }

              Future getLocation() async {
                    final location = Location();
                    var currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
                    setState(() {
                      lat = currentLocation.latitude;
                      lng = currentLocation.longitude;
                      loading=false;
                    });
                  }

             loading==false ? GoogleMap(
                 mapType: MapType.hybrid,
                 myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                 myLocationEnabled: true,
                 initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(lat, lng),
                      zoom: 15.0,
                            )):null,
```

When we go the view with map a error appear around 1s (then view load properly) with this error in the console

> I/flutter (15567): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
>   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter
>   (15567): The following assertion was thrown building
>   HomePageScreen(dirty, dependencies: I/flutter (15567):
>   [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#78c30], MediaQuery], state:
>   _HomePageScreen#9c9d2): I/flutter (15567): 'package:google_maps_flutter/src/location.dart': Failed assertion:
>   line 17 pos 16: 'latitude != I/flutter (15567): null': is not true.

I debug it and the error is relative simple: The *Location* plugin load latitude and longitude slow , *Google Maps* plugin load more fast. So we have a error.

The question is: How can i force Google map to wait location and longitude from Location plugin?

Comment: Define wait: are you hiding the map or will it have a default point?

Comment: I want to hide it while load current location. The default point is the current location (with help of Location plugin)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Show an empty `Container()` or any loading indicator while your `lat` and `lng` is null.

```
lat == null || lng == null
  ? Container()
  : GoogleMap(
      mapType: MapType.hybrid,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: 15.0,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can display a loader until you get your location,

```
var lng, lat;

      @override
      initState() {
        super.initState();
        loading = true;
        getLocation();
      }

          Future getLocation() async {
                final location = Location();
                var currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
                setState(() {
                  lat = currentLocation.latitude;
                  lng = currentLocation.longitude;
                  loading=false;
                });
              }

         loading==false ? GoogleMap(
             mapType: MapType.hybrid,
             myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
             myLocationEnabled: true,
             initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(lat, lng),
                  zoom: 15.0,
                        )):CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

Comment: are your sure when loading is false, the lat and lng are not null?

Comment: Hello I have try your answer but  `var currentLocation = await location.getLocation();` gives the problem how can I solved it? it gives the **getLocation isnt define type Location** can you help me in that

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this, and get rid of the empty `Container`.

```
GoogleMap(
      mapType: MapType.hybrid,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(lat ?? 0, lng ?? 0), // so if lat, lng is null, we use 0 as placeholder. 
        zoom: 15.0,
      ),
    )
```